# Image manipulation formula to generate effects like pictures taken via Mac's camera

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, image-manipulation, graphics

I have seen a lot of pictures of my friends with twirl and other effects taken via mac's software. Is it iPhoto?
Do you guys know where can I find the algorithm to generate such image?

Check out this video to see example of what I meant, and I know Mac has many other effects not just twirl.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BC7TsovFY_I

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like a simple tranformation in polar coordonates:

```
new_theta = theta + r * K
```

Comment: This answer is wholly incomplete.